# How do I tell scons to use clang instead of GCC?

Tags: mongodb, scons

I am building mongoDB with scons and instead of compiling it with GCC i would like it to be compiled with clang. I tried different ways to pass this info to scons but without success and I appropriate help with that. Thanks.

Comment: What ways did you try so far?

Comment: scan-build --use-c++=clang++ --use-c=clang scons mongod

Comment: I also exported CC=clang and CXX=clang++. Thanks

Comment: So do you see any output from the build? Can you paste a bit of it? Looks like CC and CXX should get picked up from command line: "scons CC=clang  CXX=clang++" should work from a quick look at their SConstruct

Comment: I eventually upgraded gcc to 5.3 as requested to avoid compiling with clang... thanks anyway,